# C++ function to fill a std::vector based on another std::vector's contents?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

This is what I have:

```
struct menuitem {
  std::string Text;
  // …
};

std::vector<menuitem> ItemList;
// populate ItemList…
std::vector<size_t> TextSizeList;
```

Now I need to fill `TextSizeList` with the lengths of each Text in each `menuitem` in ItemList…

I could do this:

```
TextSizeList.reserve(ItemList.size());
for (const item& Item : ItemList)
  TextSizeList.push_back(Item.Text.size());
```

But I was wondering if there's a `std::` function to accomplish this, something like [`std::generate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/) but with the `Generator` taking parameters, and an additional `OutputIterator`? Along the lines of:

```
void std::foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator out, Generator gen);
```

Which could then be used like this:

```
std::foo(ItemList.begin(), ItemList.end(), TextSizeList.begin(),
  [](const menuitem& Item) { return Item.Text.size(); } );
```

Comment: In what way do you need it to differ from  `std::transform`?

Comment: @TobySpeight That seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @zenith Side note: You're doing data duplication here. You're going to have to do a lot of extra code to keep these two vectors in sync and there is higher potential for error. Please don't do this. Just call `ItemList[#].size()`.

Comment: @JonathanMee `TextSizeList` is just a temporary helper variable I'm using in a function, i.e. don't worry, I'm not keeping the two vectors alive simultaneously.

Comment: @zenith The fact the `vector` only temporarily duplicates data is... only temporarily bad. Obviously this is your code so I have no say in it. But I can't think of a juncture where just calling `ItemList[#].size()` wouldn't be preferable.

Comment: @zenith: So you didn't simply read through a list of the standard algorithms? :( -1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `std::foo` you are talking about is exactly [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) + [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

```
std::transform(ItemList.begin(), ItemList.end(), std::back_inserter(TextSizeList), 
  [](const menuitem& Item) { return Item.Text.size(); });
```